# Java wear os Scroll WearableRecyclerView by digital crown

Tags: wear-os

My list is not scrolling when I use digital crown

This is what I do ;

```
<androidx.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrv_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    />


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wrv_demo);
        WearableRecyclerView wrv = findViewById(R.id.wrv_container);
        wrv.setLayoutManager(new WearableLinearLayoutManager(this));
        wrv.setAdapter(new DemoAdapter());
        wrv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        wrv.setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled(true);
        wrv.setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled(true);
        wrv.setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGenericMotion(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        wrv.setBezelFraction(0.5f);
        wrv.setScrollDegreesPerScreen(90);
    }


    private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mView;
        ViewHolder(TextView itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }
    }
    private static class DemoAdapter extends WearableRecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        private static final int ITEM_COUNT = 100;
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            TextView view = new TextView(parent.getContext());
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.mView.setText("Holder at position " + position);
            holder.mView.setTag(position);
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return ITEM_COUNT;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

short answer:
wrv.requestFocus();

long answer:
this page outlines how to capture rotary input.
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/rotary-input

I found that my WearOS app's recyclerview worked automatically in the emulator without any of what it said on that page; however, it did not work on my watch.  I implemented every step on that page and then the watch worked. Then I removed every thing on that page. For me, the only thing needed was the recyclerView.requestFocus() line.

Comment: adding wearRcViewRecFavList.requestFocus() worked, i can now scroll the list using rotoary input